# NSStatusBar title from XML data behaves erratically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmlparser, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I am wanting to "setTitle" of the NSStatusBar with a string from my XMLparser.  When the application starts, it shows the title in the status bar correctly.  However, when the XML data is refreshed, the title displays the updated string but the title moves to the left in the status bar.  I want the title to stay in the same location after the XML refreshes.

What is causing this?

upon start of the application:

[image]

after XML data is refreshed:

[image]

and here is where I'm calling the NSStatusBar:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"temp_f"]) {
        [xmlTempF appendString:@"°F"];
        [degreesF setStringValue:xmlTempF];

        statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
        [statusItem setTitle:xmlTempF];
        [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because you're creating a *new* item from `statusItemWithLength` - you shouldn't need to re-declare `statusItem`.  Try removing that line and just changing the title.